# What does the "reflecting any global.json" message mean in dotnet info output?

Tags: .net-core

This is what I see when I do a `dotnet --info` on my Windows 10 system:

[image]

It says:

> .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json)

I honestly don't understand what **"reflecting any global.json"** would mean.  Before posting this question, I did several searches and could not find any explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one runs the `dotnet` command, and multiple SDK version are installed on the system, the exact version used can be set in a `global.json`.

So I believe it means that the version printed in console is what *may* come from `global.json`, if there is such a file.

You can try this by creating `global.json` in the current directory via `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.1.600` (referring to versions available on your machine). When you use `dotnet --info` (or any other `dotnet <verb>` command), the CLI in version `2.1.600` will be used.

`global.json` file is searched for in the current directory and upwards the hierarchy, so I think it's just saying "watch out, the version you see may be different than you expected because of this `global.json` somewhere".

To confirm it's nothing extra you can even take a look at .NET Core CLI sources - [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/search?p=1&q=reflecting%20any%20global.json&unscoped_q=reflecting%20any%20global.json) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/4baa14f25f634155ef2e29d9ca400467e7a441ca/src/dotnet/Program.cs#L303). There are no special conditions why "reflecting any global.json" is printed.

Comment: You are right, I carried out the steps to create a global.json with a specific version, and dotnet reported back that version #.  Now I understand that in this context, "any" means: "if there's a global.json file in this folder, it's the version specified in that file".  Thank you!  Separately, I believe the wording could have been better chosen.  :)